# Winforms: How to get Mouse Events for Transparent Control on a Transparent Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency

I have a transparent form that overlays the desktop in a c# .NET winforms application.  The transparency is done by setting the `BackColor` to bright orange and then setting the `TransparencyKey` to the same bright orange.

So far this works great and it creates a transparent form.  I then want to create a control on the transparent form that draws a rectangle around items on the desktop.  So essentially you can think of a transparent button with a rectangular border.  To make this happen I currently extend Control and setup the control like this inside of the parent form which is also transparent:

```
public class CustomControl : Control 
{
   public CustomControl(Size size, Point point)
   {
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
      this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
      this.Size = size;
      this.Location = point;
   }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnPaint(e);
      Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f);
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, this.ClientRectangle);
   }
}
```

This creates the exact effect I'm looking for in that there is a control with a solid opaque rectangle border inside a transparent form and you can see the desktop through the control and form (see image below on left side).

[image]

The problem is that the transparent area of the control does not receive any mouse events.  In fact, it basically doesn't exist.  For example, when your mouse goes over the red rectangular border of the control that triggers the Mouse Hover, Mouse Enter, and Mouse Leave events and changes the cursor to whatever you set as `this.Cursor` for the control.  Once, the mouse is in the transparent portion of the control none of these things trigger.

How can I keep things the way they are now in regards to the look of the control but still receive mouse events in the transparent area.  In particular I want to receive Mouse Hover and have the controls `Cursor` value be honored.  Note that if I make the `BackColor` of the control anything other than `Color.Transparent` then mouse events work fine.

Thank you!

**Update**

Based on Hans comment I would like to add that we have implemented the above and that it has usually worked (i.e., the transparent area does respond to mouse events).  The reason this issue came up is because I recently rebuilt my machine with all the Windows 8.1 updates and latest ATI graphic drivers and after that the above setup no longer works ever (transparent areas on the control no longer receive any mouse events and for all intents and purposes are not part of the control)  On my colleague's machine it almost always works although we've occasionally noticed that it won't work but we could never consistently reproduce the issue.

My assumption was that we did something wrong to cause the transparent areas to not respond to mouse events.  However, based on Hans' comment, it seems as though the above code should never work and that the only reason it worked was because of a bug in Aero.

The exact color of our transparency key is `rgb(255, 128, 0)`.  In addition we did notice that any label controls placed on the transparent form look terrible (per Han's comment).

**Update 2**

Based on Han's additional comment regarding the Aero transparency bug I have the following updated questions.

1. Is there any information on this bug somewhere that explains what the bug is?
2. What is the intended behavior (assume there are no bugs) for transparent areas of a control?  Should mouse events (e.g., Mouse Hover) work on the transparent area?

**The Final Answer (that usually works)**

The answered provided by Reza below did work for me on some of my computers.  However, my primary desktop continued to stubbornly refuse to cooperate.  Even when copying the exact project between computers using the same version of windows and .NET the problem existed.  The issue when it arose was that transparent areas would not trigger mouse events and were not treated as part of the control.

In addition, I noticed the same thing Reza noticed which was that certain TransparencyKey colors flat out did not work.  Although I don't know any details of the bug I would have to agree with Hans that there are bugs involved with transparency on WinForms and if anyone is starting from scratch I would go the WPF route and save yourself any possible future headaches.

In the end we ended up implementing a work around based on some of Hans' answers that required using a timer to check the mouse location and nesting two forms (one with opacity set) to be able to manage the mouse cursor.  This solution has worked on all our systems and will hopefully hold up until we move over to WPF.  I accepted Reza's answer because it seems to work in most places but be aware that it might not work you and there is no rhyme or reason as to why.

For detailed information on the two workaround we implemented please see the following questions and answers by Hans.

[MouseHover and MouseLeave Events controlling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552809/mousehover-and-mouseleave-events-controlling)

[How can I add transparency to a c# form while keeping controls visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266920/how-can-i-add-transparency-to-a-c-sharp-form-while-keeping-controls-visible)

Comment: Take a look at this SO posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432230/transparency-and-mouse-events-winforms. Hans Passant recommended to check whether the mouse pointer is within the boundaries every 50ms.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I actually implemented Hans solution and it does work although I could not get the cursor set correctly for the control using this method as the transparent area was not being treated as part of the control.  Was hoping I might have been missing something more obvious.

Comment: Add a global mouse listener using `SetWindowsHookEx`. Then listen for the WM_MOUSE messages.

Comment: Hmm, it actually works just fine when you pick Orange as the TransparencyKey.  A bug in Aero that they can't fix anymore.  Did you actually try this?  Probably not, you haven't seen the elephant yet.  That text is going to look absolutely awful when your form is on top of another window that's, say, blue.  The anti-aliasing pixels are completely wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the question with some new information that your comment made me realize was very relevant.  The bottom line is that we have implemented this and it DID work but after recently rebuilding my desktop (updating all Windows updates and updating my graphics drivers) it no longer works.  Also, we did notice labels on the transparent form look terrible (this wasn't a huge issue because we don't need labels). Perhaps our implementation was never meant to work but  did work because of the bug you mention.  Does the bug only exist when the transparency key is Orange?

Comment: The value of TransparencyKey is critical.  There is no pattern, some trip the bug and some don't.

Comment: Thank you Hans.  Are there anymore details on this bug anywhere?  Is the bug related to the mouse events not triggering on the transparent area or is it only related to the poor rendering of text on the transparent form.  I'd be more than happy to accept any info on the bug as an answer as it does basically solve the mystery for us.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important**

Consider set `BackgroundColor` of form to Red and `TransparencyKey` to Red and `BackGroundColor` of transparent control to Transparent and it will work!

the strange thing that I see is, the approach doesn't work with for example Magenta but works with Red and Blue.

---

I think you should create your transparent control this way:

**Transparent Control Code**

```
public class TransparentControl : Control
{
    public TransparentControl()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }

    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the mouse events and rendering border when the mouse enters, here is the sample I did Using `.Net 4.5` On `Windows 8.1`:

Create a `Form` and put a `TransparentControl` that we created using above code, on it, then handle `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` and `Paint` events and paint the border when mouse is in control bouds and handle `Click` event and show a message.

**Form Code**

```
private bool drawBorder;
private void transparentControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drawBorder = false;
    transparentControl1.Invalidate();
}

private void transparentControl1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drawBorder = true;
    transparentControl1.Invalidate();
}

private void transparentControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(drawBorder)
    {
        using (var pen = new Pen(this.ForeColor, 5))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, this.transparentControl1.Width - 1, this.transparentControl1.Height - 1);
        }
    }
}

private void transparentControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

The mouse cursor is in the control's area so the black border has been painted.

**Important Note**

If you draw border the same color as form's transparency key, the border will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's okay for the mouse cursor to go in the middle of that overlay box and move with the mouse cursor and the overlay box to make it look like it's a mouse cursor.

[image]

Like this picture

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25296271)

Comment: @Nikaido this wasn't a link, it was an image...please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem when I use a picturebox control on a transparent form and use the mouseclick event over the control to trigger code. Sometimes the mouseclick is captured and sometimes it isn't. No pattern to it other than the color used as the form background. Red works fine but many other colors do not. Even black does not work consistently. I have found an almost black color that works fine when form.backcolor and form.transparencykey are set to this color. Based on this and others experiences it appears a bug in VB Studio and the way transparency is handled.

```js
Form1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 0, 0) ' a color that works with transparency and allows picturebox to be clicked
```