# Unable to change BackColor of User Control on Mouse_Enter and Mouse_Leave events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, user-controls

I am trying to change the `BackColor` property of a User Control and `ForeColor` of a label inside it. Following is my code:

```
private void NRow_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BackColor = Color.White;
   label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}

private void NRow_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BackColor = Color.Lime;
   label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

But its not working. Even I tried to add breakpoint on BackColor changing line but control is not reaching there. I also checked the event binding, its ok. The user control is added to a panel like this:

```
notContainer.Controls.Add(new NRow());
```

I don't know what is happening. Please help.

**UPDATE:**

Event handlers are attached like this:

```
this.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.NRow_MouseEnter);
this.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.NRow_MouseLeave);
```

Comment: How do you attach the event handlers to your UserControl ?

Comment: MouseEnter/Leave are very unreliable for a UserControl.  The controls inside that UC tend to get the event instead.  The only decent workaround is a Timer who's Tick event checks Cursor.Position.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12553029/17034)

Comment: But don't you think adding a timer will add an overhead to the processing?

Comment: Have you seen this discussion?
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?641685-My-UserControl-MouseEnter-Leave-Events-aren-t-firing

Comment: Have you tried to see if notContainer is getting a MouseLeave or MouseEnter event?

Comment: Well, a 200 msec timer isn't going to put a huge workload on a modern machine.  You can certainly make it event-driven, you'll need to implement the IMessageFilter.  That's where I tend to lose the crowd.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva you should post he screen shot of our `UserControl`, remember to set `BorderStyle` of both `UserControl` and `Panel` to `FixedSingle`, so that we can see how large the label covers your usercontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `label1` placed inside your user control (UC) NRow, you should be handle `MouseEnter` and `MouseEvent` of `label1` too. Because, your `label1` inside your UC can be handles your mouse events instead your UC when the mouse moves over it.

```
this.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.NRow_MouseEnter);
this.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.NRow_MouseLeave);    
label1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.NRow_MouseEnter);
label1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.NRow_MouseLeave);
```

Note: all of above lines should be placed inside your UC NRow.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by overriding the `UserControl's` [`OnMouseLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseleave.aspx) and [`OnMouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseenter.aspx) and using the [`PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) Method to determine if the mouse coordinates are still within the `UserControl` before reverting, see if something like this works for you.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Lime;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.White;

        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (! Bounds.Contains(PointToClient( MousePosition)))
        {
            BackColor = Color.White;
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to pass messages from `child controls` to your `UserControl`, in your case you need to pass the message `WM_MOUSEMOVE` plus some little code to make it work as expected:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
    Dictionary<Control,NativeControl> controls = new Dictionary<Control,NativeControl>();
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        OnMouseLeave(e);
    }                
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.HandleCreated += ControlsHandleCreated;
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }
    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.HandleCreated -= ControlsHandleCreated;
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
    }
    private void ControlsHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        NativeControl nc;
        if(!controls.TryGetValue(control, out nc)) {
           nc = new NativeControl(this);
           controls[control] = nc;
        }
        nc.AssignHandle(control.Handle);            
    }        
    public class NativeControl : NativeWindow
    {
        public NativeControl(UserControl1 parent)
        {
            Parent = parent;
        }
        UserControl1 Parent;
        bool entered;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200
            //WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201
            //WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202
            //WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84
            if (m.Msg == 0x200 || m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x202 || m.Msg == 0x84){
                //Check if Parent is not nul, pass these messages to the parent
                if (Parent != null){
                    m.HWnd = Parent.Handle;
                    Parent.WndProc(ref m);
                }
                if (m.Msg == 0x200 && !entered){
                    entered = true;
                    Parent.OnMouseEnter(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                else entered = false;
            }
            else if (entered) entered = false;
            base.WndProc(ref m);                
        }
    }
}
```