# Why are MouseEnter and MouseLeave unreliable?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552809/) question, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552809/mousehover-and-mouseleave-events-controlling/12553029#12553029) begins with `"The MouseEnter/Leave events are too unreliable to do this."` What exactly makes these events unreliable?

Comment: If you move your cursor very fast, the OS won't bother interpolating all the positions in between and so won't dispatch events in certain boundary cases.

Comment: You can leave a comment on the answer and notify the poster with the @ symbol preceding their name if you need further info from their answer.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: It appears the OP did exactly that and it was suggested that they post a new question. See Hans' comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12553029/1250301 It might be a good idea for the OP to post a comment back there to let Hans' know that he has taken his advice.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault If you look at the question you'll see that the OP left a comment there and was instructed to ask a new question.  Vicious cycle...

Comment: @MattBurland Hahaha oh wow, did not see that. But IMO it's clearly asking for more details on the answer. Well, hm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouse position is only polled every so often. It's very possible that one of those events - the mouse entering, or leaving, could occur between when the polls occur, and the events would not fire correctly.

This also makes a pretty concrete assumption that mouse movement will be continuous, rather than discrete - what if the user has a touch screen monitor? What if the mouse goes directly from inside the control to being way outside it, with no movement in between?

Comment: IMHO, what this really demonstrates is that Microsoft foobar'd their logic. A correctly written event system would *always* balance `enter` with `leave`. Infrequent polling shouldn't matter; the system can remember what events it has sent, and behave appropriately. It doesn't matter how far the mouse moved: at a given instant, it *is* either inside or outside a given control. Of course it would still be possible for it to completely miss that a control was passed over - so not send either enter or leave - but that is a different problem.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638928/199364) is a more accurate description of what goes wrong, in OP's case. [There are reports elsewhere that suggest `leave` sometimes doesn't happen after `enter`, which is what my previous comment was about.]

Answer (score 2):

You missed the point entirely. These events are *unreliable* for the **OP question**, not in general.
The question was about seeing if the `cursor` is inside the forms `client area`. Having many controls the `MouseEnter/Leave` are unreliable because you will get these events even if you are inside the form's area.

Comment: This answer is correct. To clarify:  Windows doesn't guarantee that it will send the **complete** sequence of enter/leave events that programmer expects. OP's code was written assuming the **form** would always get `enter`/`leave` events. This might not happen. Consider starting from inside one of the controls, then moving quickly to outside the entire form. Might get the `leave` of the inner control, but *never* get `enter/leave` of the form itself.

Comment: NOTE: According to Microsoft's current [WinForm control spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx), in the case I describe, `leave` **is** fired both for the inner control and the form. If this indeed happens, then the behavior has been improved in newer .Net framework versions.